# Which value of $\pi$ shall I plug in this formula $\sqrt{x} + 3 \tan x$ if $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Which value of $\pi$ shall I plug in in this formula $\sqrt{x} + 3 \tan x$ if $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$?

I used the calculator to calculate it using the $\pi$ in the calculator, but it gives me a different answer than if a plug in in the first $x$ the value of $\pi = 3.14$ and in the second $x$ the value of 180 degree. could anyone show me the mistake in the second method? and tell me what is the correct way of plugging the $\pi$ symbol?

Comment: Use radians for x and $\pi = $ 3.14 value is inaccurate. The value given in scientific calculator is more accurate than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is following: Many calculators let you choose whether you want to use [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) or [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)) for specifying angles. (Usually denoted by a `rad` or `deg` symbol somewhere on the display.)

Comment: Is it correct if I plug  in the first $x$ the value of $\pi = 3.14$ and in the second $x$ the value of 180 degree?

Comment: If your calculator is set to `deg` then yes, otherwise no. If you're not sure you could post a photo of your calculator when turned on.

Comment: if I plug in the first $x$ the value of $π=3.14$ and in the second $x$ the value of $π=3.14$ ..... the answer becomes different.

Comment: Well did you set your calculator to `deg` or `rad`? To check this try the following: If $\cos(1)$ results in $0.5403...$ then your calculator is set to radians. If it results in $0.999...$ then your calculator is set to degrees.